# Grails unit testing for artefacts created by the framework at application creation

Tags: grails

In reading "**The Definite Guide To Grails 2**". Chapter 6 discusses the URL Mappings and at the very end shows how to unit test them. There are some test code examples shown. I understand that I am to put these tests in a unit test for the `URLMappings.groovy` class but what I don't understand is how to create that unit test. Up to now, all the unit testing performed in this book as been on an artefact that has had a corresponding artefactSpec created when the original artefact was created by me(like a domain class and/or controller) but how to I go about creating a "test file" for something that the framework created when the application was created like for instance the file `URLMappings.groovy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grails create-unit-test UrlMappings
```

will create `UrlMappingsSpec.groovy` under `test\unit` in default package.

Refer [`create-unit-test`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Command%20Line/create-unit-test.html) command for more details. Also refer all available commands in the right side of the web page.